# Why is scope resolution not working on overridden variable?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, scope-resolution

When I looked at the following code sample, I thought `d.B::num` was the same as `b.num` but it isn't. It appears to be a different variable that has its own address. When I click on the run button, I see each of the three variables `b.num`, `d.num` and `d.B::num` has its associated value (3, 4 and 5 respectively).

Why is that so? And what exactly is `d.B::num` here, if it's not the same as `b.num`?

```
struct B {int num;};

struct D : public B {int num;};

int main() {

  B b;
  D d;

  b.num = 3;
  d.num = 4;
  d.B::num = 5;

  cout << b.num << endl;
  cout << d.num << endl;
  cout << d.B::num << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But... you've got two distinct objects: `b` and `d`. `d.B::num` refers to the instance of `B::num` inside the `d` instance. `b.num` is part of an entirely different instance.

Comment: `d` and `b` are different objects so obviously `d.B::num` and `b.B::num` are going to be different [sub-]objects (`B::num` isn't `static`). I'm not sure I understand what you are asking about?

Comment: You cant "override" variables.

Comment: @Charles Bailey I thought scope resolution would bring back the base variable (not the overridden one) that is why I'm confused now.

Comment: There is no overriding of variables. `D::num` hides `B::num`. A `D` instance has two `int` data members, one of them (`B`'s) is hidden. So you have to be specific about it if you want to access it.

Comment: @juanchopanza What is this feature called? Is it legal? And is it common to do that?

Comment: It is just plain *name hiding*.

Comment: @MohammadSanei: Scope resolution `B::` forces lookup to start at the base class `B` to find `num` but it's not magically going to give you the `num` belonging to an entirely separate object, it will give you the base `num` belonging to `d` (in this case).

Comment: @Charles Bailey So methods and variables are different in this respect, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instances of classes, and there are classes.  They are different things.  Much like how all integers are not the same value, different instances of a class are not the same value.

When a derived class inherits from a base class, the instances of the derived class have an instance (a subinstance really) of the base class within them.

If there is no use of the `virtual` key word, those sub instances of the derived class instance are basically perfectly normal instances of a base class.  When you create a member variable of the same name in derived as you have in base, all you do is hide the variable in the subinstance of base from casual use.  You can still get at the subinstances hidden variable by either accessing it through a pointer or reference to base, or by fully qualifying it with the `Base::x` syntax.

Despite looking like accessing a `static` variable, the `Base::x` syntax is also used to refer to names of things in base that may be hidden in derived, even if they are not `static`.

I mentioned this was only true for non-`virtual` cases.  Now, `virtual` methods in base can be overriden in derived.  You can think of `virtual` methods as being pointers to the actual methid, stored in base: wben you construct the derived instance, it goes and changes what the derived instance's base subobject's `virtual` method pointers point to to the methods of derived.  After that happens, even when you have a pointer to base, calling a `virtual` method can call a derived method.

The ofther use of `virtual` is when you inherit.  If you inherit without `virtual`, it is like the base class instances are concatenated in order as described by the order of inheritance, at the 'start' of the instance.  If you inherit with `virtual`, instead there is a table of offsets that say where the base instance is relative to the derived object.  This is mainly important in that you can have multiple subinstances of base in a given derived without `virtual`, but only one wirh `virtual` inheritance.

Some of the above is not exactly as dictated by the standard, but rather is how a compiler might implement the standards for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have:

```
B[int B::num]
```

and

```
D[int B::num, int D::num]
```

if you call `d.num` it defaults to `D::num`
if you call `d.B::num` it defaults to `B::num`

Comment: +1 (although I wouldn't call the last bit "default" -- it involves an explicit scope name after all).